# TOP 1 Record Based on Date for each record in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a variable table "@USERS" and a DB table of USERCLASS that is based on an effective date. What I need to do is to populate the USERCLASS on a determined date.
EXAMPLE:

@USERS

```
USERID | OTHER
--------------
A1     |  1
B1     |  2
C1     |  3
D1     |  4
```

DBCLASSTABLE

```
USERID | CLASS | EFFECTIVEDATE
------------------------------
A1     |  ZZ   | 2015-02-01
A1     |  XX   | 2014-02-01
B1     |  TT   | 2015-02-01
B1     |  RR   | 2014-02-01
etc..
```

Based on the date of 2015-01-01..The Class that would be in play would be the 2014 Effective classes for both.

What I have is:

```
SELECT
    USERID,
    OTHER,
    'CLASS' = (SELECT TOP 1
                   A.CLASS
               FROM
                   DBCLASSTABLE A
                   JOIN @USERS B on A.USERID = B.USERID
               WHERE A.USERID = B.USERID AND A.EFFECTIVEDATE < 2015-01-01
               ORDER BY A.EFFECTIVEDATE DESC
              )
FROM
    @USERID
```

However, I have clearly done something wrong as it returns the TOP of the DBCLASSTABLE for all records.

```
USERID | OTHER | CLASS
----------------------
A1     |  1    |  ZZ
B1     |  2    |  ZZ
C1     |  3    |  ZZ
D1     |  4    |  ZZ
```

Using this sample data, it should only return

```
USERID | OTHER | CLASS
-----------------------
A1     | 1     | XX
B1     | 2     | RR
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want a correlated subquery.  Your question mentions a table `@USERS`, but not one mentioned `@USERIDS`.  I'm going to guess they are the same:

```
SELECT USERID, OTHER,
       (SELECT TOP 1 c.CLASS
        FROM DBCLASSTABLE c
        WHERE c.USERID = u.USERID AND c.EFFECTIVEDATE < '2015-01-01'
        ORDER BY A.EFFECTIVEDATE DESC
       ) as Class
FROM @USERS u;
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for the quick response. Marking as answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```
SELECT      users.userid, users.other, class.class
from        users users
inner join  dbclass class on users.userid = class.userid
where       class.EffectiveDate < '2015-01-01'
```

You cans see this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9506c1/2

Hope this helps!!!